# Injecting resolve in child state

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to inject api into child state. My state definition looks as below.

To clarify a bit more. "api" should be the value resolved in the abstract named "root". I want to use that value in my child state named "root.some2".

```
{
  name: 'root',
  abstract: true,
  resolve: {
    provide: 'api',
    useFactory: (http) => http
      .get(AppRoute.apiUrl)
      .map((response: Response) => response.json())
      .toPromise(),
    deps: [Http]
  }
},
{
  name: 'root.some2',
  url: '/some2',
  component: Something2Component,
  resolve: [
    {
      token: 'exercises',
      resolveFn: (http, api) => http
        .get(api._links.exercises.href)
        .map((response: Response) => response.json())
        .toPromise(),
      deps: [Http, 'api']
    }
  ]
}
```

But api isn't found. I'm getting the error below.

```
Error: No provider for api!
at NoProviderError.BaseError [as constructor] (errors.js:24)
at NoProviderError.AbstractProviderError [as constructor] (reflective_errors.js:41)
at new NoProviderError (reflective_errors.js:72)
at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (reflective_injector.js:758)
at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (reflective_injector.js:786)
at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (reflective_injector.js:749)
at ReflectiveInjector_.get (reflective_injector.js:558)
at AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.get (ng_module_factory.js:95)
at UIInjectorImpl.getNative (resolveContext.js:178)
at getDependency (resolveContext.js:145)
```

Any clues about what goes wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the following causes the variable api to be defined in the child state.

```
{
  name: 'root',
  abstract: true,
  resolve: {
    api: [Http, (http) => http
      .get(AppRoute.apiUrl)
      .map((response: Response) => response.json())
      .toPromise()]
  }
},
{
  name: 'root.some2',
  url: '/some2',
  component: Something2Component,
  resolve: {
    token: 'exercises',
    resolveFn: (http, api) => http
      .get(api._links.exercises.href)
      .map((response: Response) => response.json())
      .toPromise(),
    deps: [Http, 'api']
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need an service in you resolve method yopu are going to need a resolve class insetad of a function.
Simple example:

```
@Injectable()
class MyResolver implements Resolve<MyObject> {
    constructor(private backend: Backend) {}

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any>|Promise<any>|any {
        return WhateverPromiseOrObservableYouNeed;
    }
}
```

In your router:

```
resolve: {
    resolveObject: MyResolver
}
```

Comment: But it's not a service. I simply want to use a value (api) resolved in the parent state.